# Creating a python program which tells me the age of people given their names and year of birth

Tags: python, python-3.x

Raymond 1962

Amy 1982

Jake 1978

Kevin 1970

Rosa 1981

Charles 1970

Terry 1968

Gina 1978

I have to create a program which asks the user the name of the person they want to know the age of.

```
# Storing name information

names = ['Raymond', 'Amy', 'Jake', 'Kevin', 'Rosa', 'Charles', 'Terry', 'Gina']

# Assigning year of birth 

YOB = ['1962', '1982', '1978', '1970', '1981', '1970', '1968', ',1978']

# Assigning each name in the form of a string to an integer value

Raymond = 1962
Amy = 1982
Jake = 1978
Kevin = 1970
Rosa = 1981
Charles = 1970
Terry = 1968
Gina = 1978
a = 2019

names = input('Who is the person you want to know the age of')
print('Their age is:', a - names)
```

This is what I have so far.

> Line 22: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'int' and
>   'str'.

This is the error message I have when I run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract a string from an int. Also, the YOB list contains strings, not numbers.

Why not just use a dictionary?

```
namesYOB = {
    'Raymond': 1962,
    'Amy': 1982,
    'Jake': 1978,
    'Kevin': 1970,
    'Rosa': 1981,
    'Charles': 1970,
    'Terry': 1968,
    'Gina': 1978
}
a = 2019

name = input('Who is the person you want to know the age of')

if name in namesYOB:
    print('Their age is:', a - namesYOB[name])
else:
    print('Specified person not found')
```